# MySQL: Extract total Number of Referred users from same table using JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have a query related to fetching all data from table1 with total number of referred users from each record/user.

I have one table named **table1**.

**Table:** table1

```
id    name      code    refer_from_code
1     Name1     R1      0
2     Name2     R2      R4
3     Name3     R3      R2
4     Name4     R4      R4
5     Name5     R5      R2
6     Name6     R6      R1
7     Name7     R7      R6
```

**Code** is the assigned code to that user while registration. **refer_from_code** means from which user that person registered itself. **0** means not registering on behalf of someone.

**Question:**

I want to extract the all records from table1 but also get the total number of referrals against each user with respect to refer_from_code.

**Desired results:**

```
id    name      total_referred
1     Name1     1
2     Name2     2
3     Name3     0
4     Name4     2
5     Name5     0
6     Name6     1
7     Name7     0
```

**What I have done right now:**

I have written the below query for doing this task but its not working as it should be.

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table1.COUNT(*) AS total_referred 
FROM table1 
JOIN table1 ON (table1.code=table1.refer_from_code);
```

I want to do this using single MySQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use `GROUP BY` and `LEFT JOIN` here.

```sql
SELECT
    u.name,
    IFNULL(referrals.total_referred, 0) total_referrals
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        ui.refer_from_code,
        COUNT(*) AS total_referred
    FROM users ui
    GROUP BY ui.refer_from_code
) AS referrals ON referrals.refer_from_code = u.code
ORDER BY total_referrals DESC
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ix15rofmVQoi9M2LPQcpzP/1)

Comment: Its not working. Giving me an Error. If you can create a fiddle for this it will be great. Thanks

Comment: Just added fiddle. What is the error that you're seeing?

Comment: Sir. can you do a little favor please. How can I order it by total_referrals ? I mean the users with total referrals should show first.

Comment: Updated query and fiddle for ordering by

Comment: Sir, Listen.
If there is also a column in table1 named status (can be 0 or 1). How can one more column telling about that total referrals whose status is 0 or 1. Please tell